# Upload in files in for loop

Tags: php, html, upload

I am using this upload script http://www.dropzonejs.com

The upload php part is:

```
foreach($_POST["id"] as $key=>$value)
{
    $id = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $value));
    $pre_set = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['pre_set'][$key]));
    $keep_filename = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['keep_filename'][$key]));

    $ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    $storeFolder = '../uploads';

    if (!empty($_FILES))
    {

        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

        $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;

        if($keep_filename == 'yes')
        {
            $targetFile =  $targetPath. $pre_set.'_'.$id.'_'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
        }
        else
        {
            $targetFile =  $targetPath. $pre_set.'_'.$id.'.'.pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        }

        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

    }
}
```

When using this with an standard form as shown below the file is correctly uploaded and renamed:

```
<form action="includes/upload.php" class="dropzone">

<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="id[]" name="id[]" value="'.$row['id'].'">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="pre_set[]" name="pre_set[]" value="logo">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="keep_filename[]" name="keep_filename[]" value="no">

</form>
```

But when using a for loop situation an image is shown in the upload window but the file is not uploaded.
I am not getting any errors (or not using the correct parameter to see it)

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{ $i++;
    echo'

 <div class="container">

<form action="includes/upload.php">

    <div class="form-group col-md-3">';
      if($i == 1) { echo '<label>Voeg foto toe</label>'; } echo'
        <div class="dropzone dropzone_small" id="myId'.$i.'">
            <div class="fallback">
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="id[]" name="id[]" value="xxxx">
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="pre_set[]" name="pre_set[]" value="toolbox_">
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="keep_filename[]" name="keep_filename[]" value="yes">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>';
}
```

[image]

Any suggestions to change the code to get this working?

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Start with `enctype` attribute, I suppose.

Comment: It is part of http://www.dropzonejs.com, see my first example that is working without your suggested edit.

Comment: do you want to upload multiple files?

Answer (score -1):

You must start your form with

```
<form action="includes/upload.php"> method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

// your form attributes here

```
</form>
```

Comment: It is part of http://www.dropzonejs.com, see my first example that is working without your suggested edit.